# nginx proxy_pass with new URI does not work if host is varaible

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I am trying to use variable to set the hostname in a proxy_pass, but once I try that, the path after the location is ignored.

If I try and get **localhost:8001/dirA/x/y/z.html**.  The following returns the file from http://server1:8888/dirB/dirC/x/y/z.html.  This is what I expect to happen.

```
        location ^~ /dirA/ {
            proxy_pass http://server1:8888/dirB/dirC/;
```

But if I try the following config which is just using a variable for hostname... and try and get **localhost:8001/dirA/x/y/z.html**

```
        location ^~ /dirA/ {
            set $endpoint server1;
            proxy_pass http://$endpoint:8888/dirB/dirC/;
```

I get http://server1:8888/dirB/dirC/index.html returned instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just how `proxy_pass` works. If you use a variable in the value, you need to provide the entire URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details;

You could use a regular expression `location`. For example:

```
location ~ ^/dirA/(.*)$ {
    set $endpoint server1;
    proxy_pass http://$endpoint:8888/dirB/dirC/$1;
}
```

Note that the order of regular expression locations is significant. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

---

Alternatively, a `rewrite...break` should also work.

```
location ^~ /dirA/ {
    set $endpoint server1;
    rewrite ^/dirA/(.*)$ /dirB/dirC/$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://$endpoint:8888;
}
```